# MySQL database: one media table or one table for images and one for videos?

Tags: php, mysql, image, laravel, video

I am making a social network where Users can upload and post their images and videos. Now, I don't know if it's better to make one table in my database, name it media, and have a media_type column or make separate images and videos tables. The tables would practically be the same, having an id, url, user_id and description.

Edit

I am using php laravel, and I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to setup my database. If i have only a media table it would be easier to grab all media with one function like

```
public function media()  
{  
    return $this->hasMany(Media::class);  
}
```

But maybe that is not a better option. This is my first bigger project and I don't have much experience with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a great question for S/O as it doesn't have an actual answer, but:

- Multiple table advantages: Faster when you have a few million
  records, possibly easier to code.
- Single table advantages: Possibly less disk usage.

I guess it depends on what you're looking looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added more details to my question.